# Sytnax for conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to write a Google sheet to keep track of a certain financial situation.

I have four columns: one for money 'in', the next for profit, the next for loss, then a final outcome column.

In that final outcome column, I would like to conditionally format the value so that if I have an overall loss, it colours red, and if an overall gain it colours green. I'm really new to Google Sheets, and I've tried looking at various previous questions here and on other sites but I can't quite seem to find the information that fixes my problem!

I'm very grateful in advance for any help anyone's able to give!

Answer (score 0):

To format a cell based on the value in another cell, use a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule, like this:

red:
`=C2 < 0`

green:
`=C2 >= 0`